# Why do the author choose present simple with so far

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

We wanted to send out an update to you, as we really do appreciate the continued support..

Whilst we still **enjoy** the recent and previous record releases for this year so far, we wanted to let you know that it's possible that it's going to be a quiet couple of months ahead...,

I thought that "so far" had to be used with present perfect but in this example it is with present simple, is it a mistake?

SPINOUT NUGGETS ANNOUNCEMENT

Comment: That sentence sounds quite odd, perhaps as if it's been written by a non-native English speaker.  It's difficult to say what the mistake is, because it's not obvious what the writer wanted to say.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the sentence.  They enjoy the releases: they enjoy them right now.  The releases are simply those that have happened so far this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sentence *so far* is not an adverbial modifying the predicate, but part of a prepositional phrase *for this year so far*.

The verb to which your rule would apply is the one implied in that phrase: something like *the releases **which have been issued** this year so far*.

There is no syntactic relationship between *so far* and the main verb, which is therefore not constrained to be present perfect. And it would be odd if it were, since it is expressing something that is continuing.

I would use a present continuous *Whilst we are still enjoying* rather than the present simple, but this is a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the word "still" is in the sentence, there's no need for "so far". I suggest that the sentence be changed into one of the following sentences:

*Whilst we are still enjoying the recent and previous record releases for this year, ...*

or

*Whilst we've been enjoying the recent and previous record releases for this year so far, ...*

Comment: This is wrong. There is no connection (or inconsistency) between _still_ and _for this year so far_. The first is saying what we are doing now; the second is specifying which releases we are talking about.